# Linear Regression: Correlation between predictors and residuals

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-analysis

I am reading Chapter 3 from Elements of Statistical Learning. In the explanation for Forward Stagewise Regression and Least Angle Regression, the authors explain that reducing the correlation between the predictors and the residuals amounts to moving in the direction of the standard linear regression. I also read online that in the standard linear regression (minimizing least squares), the predictors are uncorrelated with the residuals. I am not able to prove this. I have tried the following so far:

$r_i = y_i - x_i^T\hat{\beta}$

$x_i^Tr_i = x_i^Ty_i - x_i^T\hat{\beta}$

The above expression does not evaluate to $0$ for the general case. Ideally, I think I should compute $E[rX]$. I don't know how to get an empirical formula for it, since r is a vector and X is a matrix. Could someone please help me out? I am really confused. Also, it would be helpful if someone could point me to a resource explaining these correlations in more detail. I know that they should approximately have a Gaussian distribution since they are an estimate of the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{r}=[r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n]^{\top}$, $\mathbf{y}=[y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n]^{\top}$, and $\mathbf{X}=[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]^{\top}$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}^{\top}\mathbf{X}&=\big(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\hat{\beta}\big)^{\top}\mathbf{X} \\
&=\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{X}-\left(\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{y}\right)^{\top}\mathbf{X} \\
&=\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{X} \\
&=\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{X}=0,
\end{align}
which implies that the sample correlation between the residuals and the regressors is $0$ (note that $\mathbf{r}^{\top}\mathbf{i}=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i=0$).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that
$r^TX=0$ (as proved in @d.k.o.'s answer) means that the residual vector $r$ is *orthogonal* to every column in the design matrix $X$. This alone does not imply that the *sample correlation* (between $r$ and each column in $X$) is zero -- for that you need the residuals to sum to zero, which isn't always true. For example, in simple linear regression with no intercept, the residuals don't necessarily sum to zero.

A sufficient condition for the residuals to sum to zero is that a vector of all ones exists in the column space of $X$. This is the case for example, if there is an intercept term in your model.

To prove this last assertion: If a vector $\bf 1$ of all ones exists in the column space of $X$, then ${\bf 1} = Xv$ for some vector $v$. Then
$$\sum_i r_i=r^T{\bf 1}=(y-Hy)^TXv=y^T\underbrace{(I-H)X}_0v=0,$$
where we abbreviate $H:=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and use the facts $H^T=H$ and $HX=X$.